# Cache Specific responses using retrofit

Tags: android, caching, retrofit2, okhttp

I am using retrofit2 to cash responses using cache interceptor but i want to cache specifce requests not all of it so i do the following.
I define my api as:

```
public interface ExampleApi {
@GET("home/false")
@Headers("MyCacheControl: public, max-age=60000")
Observable<ExampleModel> getDataWithCache();

@GET("hello")
@Headers("MyCacheControl: no-cache")
Observable<ExampleModel> getDataWithoutCache();
 }
```

then my interceptors are:

```
public class OfflineResponseInterceptor implements Interceptor {

// tolerate 4-weeks stale
private static final int MAX_STALE = 60 * 60 * 24 * 28;
private final Context context;

public OfflineResponseInterceptor(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request request = chain.request();

    if (!NetworkUtil.isConnected(context)) {
        request = request.newBuilder()
                .removeHeader("Pragma")
                .header("Cache-Control", "public, only-if-cached, max-stale=" + MAX_STALE)
                .build();
    }

    return chain.proceed(request);
   }
}
```

and

```
public class OnlineResponseInterceptor implements Interceptor {

@Override
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {

    Request request = chain.request();
    String cacheControl = request.header("MyCacheControl");
    Logger.debug("okhttp MyCacheControl ", cacheControl + "  ");
    okhttp3.Response originalResponse = chain.proceed(request);

    return originalResponse.newBuilder()
            .removeHeader("Pragma")
            .header("Cache-Control", cacheControl)
            .build();
     }
 }
```

it is working fine but i want to know the best way to achieve what i want.also is there another way to identify my requests and differentiate between them other than Headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally,and thanks to [andre tietz](https://www.google.com.eg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwijqLr0vNvVAhVCPRQKHSq5BiIQFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmedium.com%2F%40andretietz%2Fcustom-annotations-with-retrofit-2-8701ca7ce102&usg=AFQjCNFrHzt5gVbJwr6dd1kGooU5hI9qBw) he came up with another solution through custom annoutations on the request.